# Why won't my delete function delete the node out of the BST?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I've spent hours trying to figure it out. I've checked and the delete function does find the node, but when I try to delete it by setting it as null or equal to a child node it doesn't change the tree at all when I print it out for a second time. Can anyone help me figure out what I've done wrong or at least guide me to what I need to do to fix it?

```
  class BST {
      Node root; 

      void BST () {
        root = new Node("B");
        insert (root, "A");
        insert (root, "D");
        insert (root, "C"); 
        inOrder (root);

        System.out.println (" ");
        delete (root, "D");
        //root.LEFT = null;
        inOrder (root);
      }

      void insert (Node n, String newKEY) {
        if (n.KEY.compareTo(newKEY) > 0) {

          if (n.LEFT == null) n.LEFT = new Node(newKEY);
          else if (n.LEFT != null && n.LEFT.KEY.compareTo(newKEY) < 0) n.LEFT = new Node(n.LEFT, newKEY, null);
          else insert (n.LEFT, newKEY);
        }

        if (n.KEY.compareTo(newKEY) < 0) {

          if (n.RIGHT == null) n.RIGHT = new Node(newKEY);
          else if (n.RIGHT != null && n.RIGHT.KEY.compareTo(newKEY) > 0) n.RIGHT = new Node(null, newKEY, n.RIGHT);
          else insert (n.RIGHT, newKEY);
        }

        else if (n.KEY.compareTo(newKEY) == 0) n.C++;    
      }

      void delete (Node n, String s) {
        // Visit, check if proper node, if so then delete
        if (n.KEY.compareTo(s) == 0) {
          System.out.println (n.KEY);
          // Deleting a node with no children
          if (n.LEFT == null && n.RIGHT == null) n = null; 

          //  Deleting a node with only left child
          else if (n.RIGHT == null) n = n.LEFT;

          //  Deleting a node with only right child
          else if (n.LEFT == null) n = n.RIGHT; 

          //  Deleting a node with two children
          else deleteNode_Two_Children (n, s);  
        } 
        // Left
        else if (n.KEY.compareTo(s) > 0) delete (n.LEFT, s);
        // Right 
        else if (n.KEY.compareTo(s) < 0) delete (n.RIGHT, s);  

      }

      boolean find (Node n, String s) {
        if (n.KEY.compareTo(s) > 0) {

          if (n.LEFT == null) return false;
          else if (n.LEFT != null && n.LEFT.KEY.compareTo(s) < 0) return false;
          else find (n.LEFT, s);
        }

        if (n.KEY.compareTo(s) < 0) {

          if (n.RIGHT == null) return false;
          else if (n.RIGHT != null && n.RIGHT.KEY.compareTo(s) > 0) return false;
          else find (n.RIGHT, s);
        }

        else if (n.KEY.compareTo(s) == 0) return true;   

        return false;
      }

      void deleteNode_Two_Children (Node n, String st) {
        Node s = getSuccessor(n);
        n = new Node (n.LEFT, s.KEY, s.C, n.RIGHT);
        delete (s, st);

      }

      Node getSuccessor (Node n) {
        Node temp = new Node(); 
        while (n.LEFT != null) {
          temp = n.LEFT; 
          n    = temp;
        }
        return temp; 
      }

      void inOrder (Node n) {   
        // Left
        if (n.LEFT != null) inOrder (n.LEFT);

        // Visit
        System.out.print (n.KEY + " - " + n.C + ", "); 

        // Right 
        if (n.RIGHT != null) inOrder (n.RIGHT);     
      }

      public static void main(String args[]){ 
        BST t = new BST();
        t.BST();
      }  
    }
```

```
    class Node {
      String       KEY;
      int          C;  
      Node         LEFT;
      Node         RIGHT;

      Node (String key) {
        KEY     =    key;  
        C       =    1;
        LEFT    =     null;
        RIGHT   =     null;   
      }

      Node (Node L, String key, Node R) {
        LEFT    =     L;
        RIGHT   =     R;
        KEY     =     key;  
        C       =     1;
      }

      Node (Node L, String key, int c, Node R) {
        LEFT    =     L;
        RIGHT   =     R;
        KEY     =     key;  
        C       =     c;
      }

      Node () {
        KEY     =    null;  
        C       =    0;
        LEFT    =     null;
        RIGHT   =     null;   
      }



      // If 'this' is less than 'other', a negative number will be returned, 
      // 0 if equal
      // Positive number if 'this' is greater. 
      int compare (Node other) {
        return this.KEY.compareTo(other.KEY);
      }

      boolean equals (Node other) {
        return this.KEY.equals(other.KEY);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple unit test which demonstrates the problem?  What do you see when you step through your code in your debugger in your IDE? Do you really need so many constructors?

Comment: Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is C:\Users\Willy\Desktop\Assign2
> run BST
A - 1, B - 1, C - 1, D - 1,  
D
A - 1, B - 1, C - 1, D - 1, >

Comment: I added them just in case I needed them but I intend to remove them later.

Comment: That's the name of the IDE I'm using.

Comment: I assume DrJava has a debugger.

Comment: It hasn't given me any errors, I've already checked that. The problem is that it's not actually removing the node from the tree when I go to delete it. I've checked to see that it actually finds the node, but when I set it to null the node still shows up when I reprint it. So I'm not sure why it's still printing the node even though I've set it equal to null. Do you have any idea what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your assumption that setting `n` to `null` will remove the node.  Consider the following:

```
Object x = new Object();

public void someMethod(Object o) {
    o = null;
}
```

This won't modify `x`.  Java is pass-by-value, where `o` is the reference to some `Object`.  You can certainly modify the internals of `o` through `o`'s methods:

```
o.setValue(1);
```

This works because the value of `o` is really some address on the heap, which isn't being modifed.  You can't overwrite `o` itself (eg, you can't set it to null or a `new Object()`).  In order for you to delete a node, you must find the node's parent and set it's left or right child (whichever one you with to remove) and set that to null.  Also, if that node has children, you have to make sure they aren't removed just because their parent is removed.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking it might be something like that but I didn't want to delete all my code and then later realize it was something else. Thank you, I think I know what I need to do now.